# How can I install Xcode Tools and use PacketLogger on Big Sur 11.3?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, wireshark, macos-big-sur, sniffing, xcode-tools

It's hard to find information about PacketLogger, but it seems to be a defunct Xcode tool. I'm hoping to use it on Big Sur (MBP 2017) to analyze bluetooth traffic between my iPhone and a third party device. Unfortunately I'm also having a hard time navigating the developer.apple.com page to find this set of tools.

Because I was unable to find any compatible Xcode *Tools* versions after 2006, I downloaded an older version of Xcode (13.2) via xcodereleases.com from apple's servers, and inspected the package contents to no avail. Ultimately, I am hoping to import the info collected by PL into wireshark.

Still very much learning the fundamentals of bluetooth protocol so thank you for being patient with this broad noob question. I appreciate any info that can help me narrow my question!